# When Android Textview Draw Multi-Line strings, The Layout Redrawn?

Tags: android, textview, draw, multiline, bringtofront

1. This is the code.

   ```
   RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
   TextView title = new TextView(this);
   title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
   title.setWidth(320);
   title.setHeight(160)
   title.setText("hello");
   layout.addView(title);
   layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
   ```
2. On the Screen, when I move the view location from (x:0, y:0) -> to (x: 200, y:300)
3. And then set the TextView's value

   ```
   title.setText("aaaaabbbbbbccccccdddddddeeeeeeeddddd");
   ```

   > the string length > textview's width, so multi-line display
4. **Then occurred error is "the TextView's location is back to (x:0, y:0)"**

   > if the TextView is display SingleLine,  eg: title.setText("aaa"); the TextView's location is (x:200, y:300)

### Is the android textView display multi-line strings, the layout is Redrawn? anyone can help me? I've been worried all night!!!

ps: the same error is also happened when call the TextView.bringToFront();

// In Android，if you changed the view location，must be setting layoutparams；otherwise，when the view reDraw，the view will back to location(0,0)。

// the solution is like this：

```
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpFeedback = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(  
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
                lpFeedback.leftMargin = v.getLeft();  
                lpFeedback.topMargin = v.getTop();  
                lpFeedback.setMargins(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), 0, 0);  
                v.setLayoutParams(lpFeedback);
```

Comment: // when the view location changed，must be also change layoutparams
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpFeedback = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(  
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
                    lpFeedback.leftMargin = v.getLeft();  
                    lpFeedback.topMargin = v.getTop();  
                    lpFeedback.setMargins(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), 0, 0);  
                    v.setLayoutParams(lpFeedback);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't happen like that here is a sample code try this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        TextView title = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        tvlp.setMargins(200,300,0,0);
        title.setLayoutParams(tvlp);

        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        title.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        title.setWidth(320);
        title.setHeight(160);
        title.setText("helloaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        title.setTextSize(22);
        layout.addView(title);
        setContentView(layout, rlp);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: thanks, it give me some inspiration，solved my problem。